# If $M$ is $R$-module then prove that $M$ is $R/I$-module for an ideal $I$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let , $M$ be a $R$-module and $I$ be an ideal of $R$ such that $I\subset \text{Ann}(M)$ Then , prove that $R$ is $R/I$-module under $\bar{x}.m=xm$ , where , $\bar x\in R/I$ and $m\in M$.

Let , $\bar x, \bar y\in R/I$ and $m,m_1,m_2\in M$. Then , we have ,

$\bar x.(m_1+m_2)=x.(m_1+m_2)=xm_1+xm_2=\bar x.m_1+\bar x.m_2$

$(\bar x+\bar y).m=\overline{x+y}.m=(x+y).m=x.m+y.m=\bar x.m+\bar y.m$

$\bar 1.m=1.m=m$

**Question :** Where the condition $I \subset \text{Ann}(M)$ is required ?

Comment: Why is the operation you defined independent of the choice of representative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need $I\subset \text{Ann}(M)$ in the definition of $\overline x\cdot m$. One has $\overline x=\overline{x'}$ when $x'=x+u$ with $u\in I$.
But one needs $\overline x\cdot m=\overline{x'}\cdot m$. This boils
down to $xm=(x+u)m$, so one needs $um=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $I$ is not contained in $Ann(M)$, then there is a nonzero $i \in I$ such that $i.m \ne 0$ for some $m \in M$. Thus, $\overline{i}.m=i.m \ne 0$, violate the axiom for $R/I$-module.

Comment: Not getting your point ! 
$\bar i.m \not =0$ .How it violates axiom of $R/I$ module ?

Comment: Since $\overline{i}$ and $\overline{0}$ are equivalence in $R/I$ (both are elements of $I$), we need $\overline{i}.m=\overline{0}.m=0.m=0$.

Comment: Got it............